# Why are session methods unbound in sqlalchemy using sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Code replicating the error:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'messages'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    message = Column(Integer)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + filename_of_your_choice)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

newmessage = Message()
newmessage.message = "Hello"

messages = session.query(Message).all()
```

Running this code yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/aaron/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    session.commit()
TypeError: unbound method commit() must be called with Session instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I'm 95% positive that the filename isn't the issue as I can connect to it from the shell

any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The return value from `sessionmaker()` [is a class](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#getting-a-session). You need to instantiate it before using methods on the instance.

Comment: @Jay: Same way I instantiate any class in Python.

Comment: @ignacio - hey, thanks for coming back. Please forgive my ignorance, but I am trying to fix the same error, but can't see from this answer *how* to fix, just what I need to do!

Comment: @Jay: It's a class. You call it. `sc = SomeClass()`