# Error with sessionmaker

Tags: python, class, sqlalchemy

I can see from this question [Why are session methods unbound in sqlalchemy using sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221814/why-are-session-methods-unbound-in-sqlalchemy-using-sqlite) that I need to instantiate the class for sessionmaker.

I get the same error, and I assume the 'fix' will work, only I have no idea how to 'instantiate the class'

My set up code is as per the linked question.

From this question [How to instantiate a class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396856/how-to-instantiate-a-class-in-python) I can see that I need to call the class object, and my erroneous assumption is that the:

```
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
```

line is the instantiation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your problem is exactly the same as the first question you posted, and the solution should be the same as the selected answer from the same question.

The function `sessionmaker` returns a **class**, binding the engine passed in the `bind` parameter.

So, after creating the class, you have to instantiate it (haven't instantiate it yet):

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
# Session is a class
session = Session()
# now session is a instance of the class Session
session.execute(...)
```

Comment: Awesome, I was aware they are the same, I just didn't know how to the middle step of actually calling it as an object rather than as a class. Thank you for setting me straight.

Answer (score 7):

That line creates the Session class. You still need to instantiate it.

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```